# Migration exception: alter table --> Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name

Tags: mysql, doctrine, flow-framework

After doing `php flow flow:doctrine:migrate`... 
I got following error:

`An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE user ADD gdisplayname LONGTEXT DEFAULT NULL, ADD tdisplayname LONGTEXT DEFAULT NULL, ADD fdisplayname LONGTEXT DEFAULT NULL':
SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'gdisplayname'`

I tried to remove the already existing column using:

```
ALTER TABLE user DROP COLUMN gdisplayname;
```

and then reusing `php flow flow:doctrine:migrate`

It does not work. How can I remove this errors without the need to dump the whole database and to successfully migrate the database?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a migration is already applied, you can set it as migrated so Flow won't try to apply it again. First, check which migration is causing the error

```
./flow doctrine:migrationstatus
```

Then set it as migrated:

```
./flow:doctrine:migrationversion --version <version> --add
```

Answer (score 0):

Just tried @lorenz answer and there's a minor difference in syntax if you're using Symfony console for both commands.

To check migrations status:

```
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:status
```

To set as migrated:

```
 php bin/console doctrine:migrations:version 'DoctrineMigrations\<version>' --add
```